# The effects of air resistance on the maximum height of a ball in the air

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, projectile, drag

I want to assume a situation where a ball is launched vertically into the air at a 90° angle. Assume that it is on a non-moving ground surface (flat earth) and there is no air flow. I know that the ball should reach maximum height at the turning point of the parabola, PROVIDED there is no air resistance. Gravity is a constant pull as well.

However, I wish to account for air resistance. Is there still any way to model this using an exact equation as a solution? I have tried to do so, but was unable to do it.

Comment: The only factors I want to account for are the effect of gravity(ball has a constant mass of 2.7 grams), surface area(around 3.2cm^2), and the air resistance. Everything else is directly simplified: the ball launched straight up vertically, no wind, no rotation of earth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't be easy, that's for sure. But it can be done. Start with the [drag equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)). The force due to air resistance is:

$F = k v^2$

where $v$ is the velocity, and $k$ is a coefficient that depends on, among other things, the density of air, the surface area of your object, and the drag coefficient. Then add up the forces on your body:

$F = ma = -kv^2 - mg$

Note how although $k$, $m$ and $g$ are constants, $v$ is not. So you'll need to solve a differential equation:

$F = m dv/dt = -kv^2 - mg$

This yields an equation that gives you the velocity as a function of time. You can then solve this for the time at which the velocity is $0$, which corresponds to the maximum height. Using the same equation, you can integrate it (remember $v = dx/dt$ by definition) to get the position $x$ as a function of time. There'll be an arbitrary constant, which you can fix using your initial conditions. Then substitute the value of time you got earlier for the maximum height, and find the position.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139246/discussion-on-answer-by-allure-the-effects-of-air-resistance-on-the-maximum-heig).